# iOS - Pass data from one viewcontroller to use in the init method of another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xlform

I'm able to pass data between two view controllers using the prepareForSegue method. But in that way, the passed data cannot be used in the second view controller's **init** method.

Also, I'm using XLForm. So accessing data inside the init method is necessary.

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Here's the first view controller's prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SessionToWorkout"])
    {
        WorkoutsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cellName = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

        NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
        sectionName = sectionTitle;

        vc.sectionName = sectionName;
        vc.cellName = cellName;
    }

}
```

And here's the initWithCoder method of the second view controller:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder

    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
        if (self) {
            //Retrieve Workouts from DB
            NSString *day_id;

            day_id = [[DBHandler database] getDayIdWhere:@[@"day_name"]
                                             whereValues:@[cellName]];

            workoutsArray = [[DBHandler database] getWorkoutsForDayWhere:@[@"day_id"]
                                                             whereValues:@[day_id]];

            AppLog(@"Workouts array %@", workoutsArray);

            [self initializeForm];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Inside the initWithCoder method, I need to use the **cellName** variable's value (which has been passed to this view controller from the previous view controller) to call the database method.

Any idea or suggestions how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `didSet` observer of your variable in order to initialize your database.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the didSet observer. Can you explain further?

Comment: I've just added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The `didSet` observer is called when a variable is modified (it's not called when the variable is initialized). Initialize the database when the **cellName** is set :

**Swift:**

```
var cellName : String = "" {
    didSet {
     // The cell name has been set, create the database here as in any other function
    }
}
```

---

**Objective-C:**

It's quite similar in objective C, but you don't have a `didSet` observer, instead use a custom setter. The only difference is, since it's a setter, that you have to set your variable

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * cellName;

-(void)setCellName:(NSString *)newValue
{
    // First, set the new value to the variable
    _cellName = newValue;

    // The cell name has been set, create the database here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. oh wait, this is swift right? But I'm using objective-c :/

Comment: Oh my bad, you can also do it in Objective C. Let me edit my answer !

Comment: Another problem, I'm setting the value for this "cellName" variable in the previous view controller's prepareForSegue method. So it's already set.
But when I'm trying to access it inside the initWithCoder method, it gives me a null value. Maybe because the "initWithCoder" method is called before the value is set?
And if so, is there any way that I can set the value of this variable at the time the "initWithCoder" method is called?

Comment: You can't set the value before `initwmithcoder`since it's the method which initialize your object. Thus your value is null (or your default value), in `initwmithcoder`. You have to use this value inside the custom setter, or if you prefer you can also  created a custom init function with a new parameter for this string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SessionToWorkout"])
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    WorkoutsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //you can get cell value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath fun
    cellName = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    sectionName = sectionTitle;
    [vc setSectionName: sectionName];
    [vc setCellName: cellName];
    //check it have right value
    NSLog(@"Cell name %@ Section name %@", cellName ,sectionName);
    //*** in viewControllerB set sectionName, cellName as @property and set it to @synthesize 
}
```